# Using checkbox to show/hide dynamic divs doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a webpage that uses javascript and ajaxpage to load a page inside another page without having to refresh. The code looks like this:

```
<a href="javascript:ajaxpage('r/gd.php','releases');">LINK</a>
```

Clicking on LINK will load 'r/gd.php' into the DIV I have labeled as 'releases'. I got the backbone of the code to accomplish this from this website here:

> http://dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex17/ajaxcontent.htm

This all works great until I attempt to use checkboxes to filter the content of a DIV on a loaded page. What I would like to do is have a series of checkboxes with unique IDs like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="all"> Show All
<input type="checkbox" id="red"> Red
<input type="checkbox" id="orange"> Orange
<input type="checkbox" id="yellow"> Yellow
```

These would then show/hide various DIVs when checked/unchecked that contain a series of classes like so:

```
<div id="box" class="all red"><?php echo $gdclock; ?></div>
<div id="box" class="all red orange"><?php echo $gdheart; ?></div>
<div id="box" class="all orange"><?php echo $gdblue; ?></div>
<div id="box" class="all red orange yellow"><?php echo $gdwhite; ?></div>
<div id="box" class="all yellow"><?php echo $gdclearsplat; ?></div>
<div id="box" class="all red yellow"><?php echo $gdredblack; ?></div>
```

I'm not sure how to accomplish this on a page that is loaded the way I am doing so. I have used examples such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48300202/17146620) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35034161/17146620) that work great when just visiting a URL, but as soon as I go to use the same code on a dynamically loaded page, it does nothing.

Is there something I am missing here? This is a [link to my webpage](http://alkalinetrio.rf.gd/) (best viewed on desktop). If you click on ALL ALBUMS in the left side bar, a page full of vinyl records will load with checkboxes at the top. I'd like to filter based on colour (using classes/IDs as described above) and hide everything else. Have more than one checkbox active at a time is ideal.

Comment: Hi and Welcome to SO. please take the [tour] first. Then 
read [how to ask questions here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). After 
that edit the question to meet the guidelines and provide 
a [repro] for debugging details (compiled version that shows the issue not php). Please also read: [Can I just link to my website?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/). Questions must always be self containing without requiring to use external resources. What have you tried with JS so far?

Comment: PS: AN ID must be unique. Using an ID multiple times is invalid HTML.

Comment: Can you include the code for the function `ajaxpage` and some sample data from that the Ajax call?

Answer (score 0):

Your original question does not seem to show a link between the Ajax call and selectively turning on/off Html elements. Is this what you are seeking?

```js
$(document).ready(() => {
  $("#all div").hide();
  $("p#checkboxes > :checkbox").change(() => {
    $("#all div").hide();
    if ($("#all").is(":checked")) $("#all div").show();
    else {
      if ($("#red").is(":checked")) $(".red").show();
      if ($("#orange").is(":checked")) $(".orange").show();
      if ($("#yellow").is(":checked")) $(".yellow").show();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p id="checkboxes">
  <input type="checkbox" id="all"> Show All
  <input type="checkbox" id="red"> Red
  <input type="checkbox" id="orange"> Orange
  <input type="checkbox" id="yellow"> Yellow
</p>

<div id="all">
  <div class="red">Only red stuff</div>
  <div class="red orange">red & orange stuff</div>
  <div class="orange">Only orange stuff</div>
  <div class="red orange yellow">anything</div>
  <div class="yellow">Only yellow things</div>
  <div class="red yellow">Red & yellow</div>
</div>
```

If above is not what you need, please provide more details in your question.

Comment: This code is exactly what I want to do. When I add it to my website, it works flawlessly on its own (http://alkalinetrio.rf.gd/flowers.php). However, when I use ajaxpage to load the flowers.php page it doesn't work 99% of the time. Sometimes it will run, but most of the time it will not. The code for ajaxpage can be found here: http://dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex17/ajaxcontent.htm

Is something conflicting? I don't understand why this is happening.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have posted a new question about dynamic ajax page launching working properly with javascript. I hope I have asked my question correctly. It is here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/69622581/17146620