# Launching a dynamic page with Ajax seems to break some Javascript function

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, ajax

I have a website that uses a javascript code called ajaxpage to load .php pages dynamically. The website is http://alkalinetrio.rf.gd. I have a sidebar with links that load a specified page into a DIV class of my choosing (in this case, it is the 'flowers' link on the left. The code looks like this:

```
<a href="javascript:ajaxpage('flowers.php','releases'); loadobjs('flowers.js')">flowers</a>
```

The javascript for ajaxpage can be found here: [Ajaxpage](http://dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex17/ajaxcontent.htm)

What the line of code I provided above does, is load flowers.php into a DIV element with the class 'releases'. Upon clicking the 'flowers' link, the ajaxpage code also loads an additional javascript called flowers.js (that is what the loadobjs('flowers.js') part is doing).

The full code of flowers.php is the following:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>TEST PAGE</title>
</head>
    
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<body>
    
<div class="gallery" style="color:white;">
<p id="checkboxes">
  <input type="checkbox" id="all"> Show All
  <input type="checkbox" id="red"> Red
  <input type="checkbox" id="orange"> Orange
  <input type="checkbox" id="yellow"> Yellow
</p>

<div id="all">
  <div class="red">Only red stuff</div>
  <div class="red orange">red & orange stuff</div>
  <div class="orange">Only orange stuff</div>
  <div class="red orange yellow">anything</div>
  <div class="yellow">Only yellow things</div>
  <div class="red yellow">Red & yellow</div>
</div>
</div>
    
</body>
</html>
```

And the full code for flowers.js is the following:

```
// JavaScript Document
$(document).ready(() => {
  $("#all div").hide();
  $("p#checkboxes > :checkbox").change(() => {
    $("#all div").hide();
    if ($("#all").is(":checked")) $("#all div").show();
    else {
      if ($("#red").is(":checked")) $(".red").show();
      if ($("#orange").is(":checked")) $(".orange").show();
      if ($("#yellow").is(":checked")) $(".yellow").show();
    }
  });
});
```

When I visit the [flowers.php page directly](http://alkalinetrio.rf.gd/flowers.php), everything works as intended. However, if I use the ajaxpage javascript to load flowers.php within a DIV, the code does not work as intended. 99% of the time it does nothing, but once in a while it does work. If I load another page into the DIV with ajaxpage, and then return to flowers.php, the code will always do nothing.

I'm seeking help to understand and fix the issue of dynamically loading a page into a DIV using ajaxpage, and how to remedy the flowers.js script not working as intended. I am trying to show/hide elements with checkboxes while having a page loaded dynamically and it is not working. I am open to any fix for this issue; hopefully I have described the problem accurately.

Comment: The `ajaxpage` function inserts the Html source using `innerHTML`.  Any embedded scripts won't work. Seems like the framework you are using at alkalinetrio.rf.gd provides a function`loadobjs` for you to load scripts. Looks like you have to save the scripts separately to a different file.

Comment: I am using loadobjs to load the javascript. The page loads, and the javascript mostly works, but there are a few issues I'm now facing. I have posted a new question about the javascript here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/69693263/17146620

Clicking the Show All link hides/shows the entire DIV, but the individual checkboxes do not hide/show based on class. Style tags get added to all DIVs, which I do not want. I'm afraid I may not have included all relevant information before. Hopefully I have now.