# Prevent this Javascript from applying a style change across all DIVs

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have some Javascript code that shows/hides elements based on checkboxes, but it does it a little too well! The current code I have applies a style change across all DIVs, but I would like it to only apply to one element with a specific ID, and leave everything else alone. How can I change the Javascript to do what I would like? Here is all relevant code:

The Javascript:

```
const clicked = () => {
  $("#all div").hide();
  $("p#checkboxes > :checkbox").change(() => {
    $("#all div").hide();
    if ($("#showall").is(":checked")) $("#all div").show();
    else {
      if ($("#red").is(":checked")) $(".red").show();
      if ($("#orange").is(":checked")) $(".orange").show();
      if ($("#yellow").is(":checked")) $(".yellow").show();
      if ($("#green").is(":checked")) $(".green").show();
      if ($("#blue").is(":checked")) $(".blue").show();
      if ($("#purple").is(":checked")) $(".purple").show();
      if ($("#clear").is(":checked")) $(".clear").show();
      if ($("#black").is(":checked")) $(".black").show();
      if ($("#white").is(":checked")) $(".white").show();
      if ($("#brown").is(":checked")) $(".brown").show();
      if ($("#grey").is(":checked")) $(".grey").show();
      if ($("#pink").is(":checked")) $(".pink").show();
      if ($("#marble").is(":checked")) $(".marble").show();
      if ($("#smoke").is(":checked")) $(".smoke").show();
      if ($("#trans").is(":checked")) $(".trans").show();
      if ($("#opaque").is(":checked")) $(".opaque").show();
      if ($("#split").is(":checked")) $(".split").show();
      if ($("#double").is(":checked")) $(".double").show();
      if ($("#splat").is(":checked")) $(".splat").show();
      if ($("#og").is(":checked")) $(".og").show();
    }
  });
};
```

The Page Code:

```
<?php include '../masterpressing.php' ?>
<link href="../css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<?php 
ob_start();
require '../r/gd.php';
require '../r/micf.php';
require '../r/fhti.php';
require '../r/gm.php';
require '../r/crimson.php';
require '../r/ai.php';
require '../r/ta.php';
require '../r/msit.php';
require '../r/ittc.php';
require '../r/st.php';
require '../r/remains.php';
require '../r/damnesia.php';
require '../r/pastlive.php';
ob_end_clean();
?>


<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>All Albums TEST</title>
</head>
    
<style> 
    #checkboxes {
        margin: 1px;
    }

    .x {
        display: none;
    }   
</style>
    
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>

<?php echo $stickybar; ?>

<div class="sortboxes">
<p id="checkboxes">
<input type="checkbox" id="showall" onclick="clicked()"> Show All
<input type="checkbox" id="red" onclick="clicked()"> Red
<input type="checkbox" id="orange" onclick="clicked()"> Orange
<input type="checkbox" id="yellow" onclick="clicked()"> Yellow
<input type="checkbox" id="green" onclick="clicked()"> Green
<input type="checkbox" id="blue" onclick="clicked()"> Blue
<input type="checkbox" id="purple" onclick="clicked()"> Purple
<input type="checkbox" id="clear" onclick="clicked()"> Clear
<input type="checkbox" id="black" onclick="clicked()"> Black
<input type="checkbox" id="white" onclick="clicked()"> White
<input type="checkbox" id="brown" onclick="clicked()"> Brown
<input type="checkbox" id="grey" onclick="clicked()"> Grey
<input type="checkbox" id="pink" onclick="clicked()"> Pink
<input type="checkbox" id="marble" onclick="clicked()"> Marble
<input type="checkbox" id="smoke" onclick="clicked()"> Smoke
<input type="checkbox" id="trans" onclick="clicked()"> Trans
<input type="checkbox" id="opaque" onclick="clicked()"> Opaque
<input type="checkbox" id="split" onclick="clicked()"> Split
<input type="checkbox" id="double" onclick="clicked()"> 2xLP
<input type="checkbox" id="splat" onclick="clicked()"> Splatter
<input type="checkbox" id="og" onclick="clicked()"> OG
</p>
</div>

<!---|----------------------------------------------------------------------------------->
<div class="album-title">All Studio Albums <?PHP print $skull; ?> 230 Variants</div>
<!---|----------------------------------------------------------------------------------->
<div class="gallery">
<div id="all">
<div id="box" class="black x"><?php print $gdclock; ?></div>
<div id="box" class="black x"><?php echo $gdheart; ?></div>
<div id="box" class="blue x"><?php echo $gdblue; ?></div>
<div id="box" class="white opaque og x"><?php echo $gdwhite; ?></div>
<div id="box" class="clear red og splat x"><?php echo $gdclearsplat; ?></div>
<div id="box" class="red black split ogs opaque x"><?php echo $gdredblack; ?></div>
<div id="box" class="red black splat ogs trans x"><?php echo $gdredsplat; ?></div>
<div id="box" class="purple yellow split splat og trans x"><?php echo $gdpurpleyellowsplat; ?></div>
<div id="box" class="green yellow split splat og trans x"><?php echo $gdgreenyellowsplat; ?></div>
<div id="box" class="red og trans x"><?php echo $gdredtrans; ?></div>
</div>
</div>
    
</body>
</html>
```

The block of code that **< ?php print $gdclock; ? >** prints:

```
<?php $gdclock =<<<ALK
<div class="container"> 
  <a href="img/12/GD/clock-a.jpg" data-lightbox="main2" data-title="{$inf[gdclock]}"><img src="img/12/GD/tb/clock-a.jpg" class="image" onerror="imgError(this);"></a>
  <div class="pressing">First Pressing</div>
  <div class="total"><div class="outof">PRESSING OF</div> 1000</div>
  <div class="album-colour">Black (Clock Face Labels)
   <div class="more-images">
    <a href="img/12/GD/clock-a.jpg" data-lightbox="main" data-title="{$inf[gdclock]}">
       <a href="img/12/GD/clock-b.jpg" data-lightbox="main" data-title="{$inf[gdclock]}"><img src="img/12/GD/tb/clock-b.jpg" class="image-bar" onerror="this.onerror=null; this.remove();"></a>
       <a href="img/12/GD/clock-cover.jpg" data-lightbox="main" data-title="{$inf[gdclock]}"><img src="img/12/GD/tb/clock-cover.jpg" class="image-bar" onerror="this.onerror=null; this.remove();"></a>
       <a href="img/12/GD/clock-back.jpg" data-lightbox="main" data-title="{$inf[gdclock]}"><img src="img/12/GD/tb/clock-back.jpg" class="image-bar" onerror="this.onerror=null; this.remove();"></a>
       <a href="img/12/GD/clock-insert.jpg" data-lightbox="main" data-title="{$inf[gdclock]}"><img src="img/12/GD/tb/clock-insert.jpg" class="image-bar" onerror="this.onerror=null; this.remove();"></a>
   </div>
  </div>
</div>
ALK;
?>
```

My issue at the moment, is when I click on any of the checkboxes a style="display: none;" tag gets applied to every DIV in my block of code above. I would like the tag to only be applied to the DIVs with an id="box" in my Page Code. Ideally what should happen, is when I click the checkbox with id="red", all of the DIVs with id="box" and with red in their class will be be visible, while all other DIVs with id="box" and no red in their class name will be hidden (style="display: none;"). When unchecked, the style should be removed. I just don't know how to write the Javascript to incorporate the id="box" check. I hope I explained this properly.

(I know that using the same id= more than once in a page is bad html, but it is the only way I could get my DIVs to obey my style rules. Using class didn't seem to work correctly in that section, whereas using id= to stylize works).

Comment: Any reason why the `change` event is inside the function `clicked`?  `const clicked = () => {
  $("#all div").hide();
  $("p#checkboxes > :checkbox").change(() => { ...`

Comment: If you want to select multiple elements with some common characteristics, instead of ids, use class, like `$(".red")` which will return all elements with the class `red`. You have already done this correctly.

Comment: There is some convoluted logic in your event handlers. In your Html markup, for each checkbox, you have tied the `onclick` event to `clicked`. But inside `clicked` you defined a new function for the `onchange` event for every checkbox.  The event handlers accumulate every time you click something. Put in a `console.log` statement and you will see what I mean. If you want to use the `onclick` in Html, remove the line `$("p#checkboxes > :checkbox").change(() => {` and its closing `}`. Even thought it might work, it is wrong.

Comment: Your code on the actual web site is different from the code in your question. The `Show All` checkbox has` id=all` on the web site, but in the script, it is selecting `$("#showall")`. This could be the reason why it is not working.

Answer (score 1):

I think your primary issue is that you are not hiding the other divs. try something like:

HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="orange" onclick="clicked()"> test
<input type="checkbox" id="red" onclick="clicked()"> test
<div id="oj" style="display:none;">oj</div>
<div id="r" style="display:none;">r</div>
```

JS:

```
        clicked = () => {
            if($('#orange').is(":checked")) {
                $("#oj").show()
            } else {
                $("#oj").hide()
            }
            if($('#red').is(":checked")) {
                $("#r").show()
            } else {
                $("#r").hide()
            }
        };
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You should **NOT** use the same IDs more then once per page. This is sematically incorrect. It works with jQuery just because this is how elements selecting with jQuery works. What you should do is make additional class name for all of the `<div>` elements you want to show or hide. This will allow you to safely select which divs should be hidden.

Here is more clear example of how you can make the same logic without duplicated IDs or huge amount of conditions. I used `.single-entry` class name for all the `<div>` i wanted to toggle.

```js
// Wait for page to load
$(function () {
  console.info('Loaded!');

  // Checking for change event of the checkboxes
  $('.checkboxes input[type=checkbox]').change(function () {
    console.info('Checkbox change detected!');

    // Hiding all of the divs we need to hide or show depending on the ckecboxes checked
    // We use 'single-entry' class name for all the divs instead of IDs
    // IDs should *always* be unique for each element
    $('.entries .single-entry').hide();

    // Show all entries if 'all' checkbox is set
    if ($('.checkboxes input[type=checkbox]#all').is(':checked')) {
      console.info('All entries should be shown!');
      $('.entries .single-entry').show();
      return;
    }

    // Now loop all checked checkboxes and show related entries
    $('.checkboxes input[type=checkbox]:checked').each(function () {
      const $checkbox = $(this);
      const checkboxElementId = $checkbox.attr('id');

      console.log(`Checking for entries with class name .${checkboxElementId}`)

      // We already checked 'all' checkbox before, skip it
      if (checkboxElementId === 'all') {
        console.log("We don't need to check this checkbox!");
        return;
      }
      
      // Show entry if it found in the list of entries
      $('.entries .single-entry.' + checkboxElementId).show();
    })
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- this is list of checkboxes you listen -->
<div class="checkboxes">
  <div>
    <label for="all">
      <input type="checkbox" id="all" checked>
      <span>Show all</span>
    </label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="red">
      <input type="checkbox" id="red">
      <span>Red</span>
    </label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="blue">
      <input type="checkbox" id="blue">
      <span>Blue</span>
    </label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="green">
      <input type="checkbox" id="green">
      <span>Green</span>
    </label>
  </div>
</div>

<hr>

<!-- 
  list of entries you displaying or hiding
  it's better if you will contain them in some fixed class name
-->
<div class="entries">
  <!-- 
    all of the entries should use single class which will indicate 
    that this div should be displayed or hidden
  -->
  <div class="single-entry red">This is red entry</div>
  <div class="single-entry green">This is green entry</div>
  <div class="single-entry blue">This is blue entry</div>
  <div class="single-entry green blue">This is green and blue entry</div>
  <div class="single-entry blue red">This is blue red entry</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some event handler logic errors and a typo:

```
const clicked = () => {
    $("#all div").hide();
    if ($("#all").is(":checked")) $("#all div").show();
    else {
      if ($("#red").is(":checked")) $(".red").show();
      if ($("#orange").is(":checked")) $(".orange").show();
      if ($("#yellow").is(":checked")) $(".yellow").show();
      if ($("#green").is(":checked")) $(".green").show();
      if ($("#blue").is(":checked")) $(".blue").show();
      if ($("#purple").is(":checked")) $(".purple").show();
      if ($("#clear").is(":checked")) $(".clear").show();
      if ($("#black").is(":checked")) $(".black").show();
      if ($("#white").is(":checked")) $(".white").show();
      if ($("#brown").is(":checked")) $(".brown").show();
      if ($("#grey").is(":checked")) $(".grey").show();
      if ($("#pink").is(":checked")) $(".pink").show();
      if ($("#marble").is(":checked")) $(".marble").show();
      if ($("#smoke").is(":checked")) $(".smoke").show();
      if ($("#trans").is(":checked")) $(".trans").show();
      if ($("#opaque").is(":checked")) $(".opaque").show();
      if ($("#split").is(":checked")) $(".split").show();
      if ($("#double").is(":checked")) $(".double").show();
      if ($("#splat").is(":checked")) $(".splat").show();
      if ($("#og").is(":checked")) $(".og").show();
    }
};
```

Each checkbox has the `onclick` event assigned to the function `clicked`. In `clicked`, each checkbox has a function added to the `change` event:

```
$("p#checkboxes > :checkbox").change(() => { /* code here */ }
```

Every time you click a checkbox, the code is *added* to the `change` of every checkbox. So the second time you click a checkbox, that code runs twice. This event handler just keeps accumulating!

The other error is you had `$("#showall")`. There is no element with an id of `showall`. It should be `$("#all")`.